# Expresso: Store - 0 handling charges when selecting a particular shipping method

Tags: expresso-store, shipping

I have a webstore which has products that add a different handling charge to the shipping if the user selects 'registered mail' shipping.

How do I set the handling charges to 0 when a user selects a particular shipping method (Pick up at store)?

Regards,
Rin

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this would be to use the Default Shipping Plugin with a name of "Store Pickup" or similar. Then create a new rule that does not add any cost. Then you can create a second Default Shipping Plugin (actually you can use any Shipping gateway) instance for your regular delivery items that will allow you to calculate shipping cost based upon rules supplied.